# How can I get selected row data in kendo

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-contextmenu

I'm using [this context menu example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/context-menu).

I used the context menu select event like this:

```
menu = $("#menu").kendoContextMenu({
    target: "#listview-context-menu",
    filter: ".product",
    animation: {
        open: { effects: "fadeIn" },
        duration: 500
    },
    select:  onSelect
});

function onSelect(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

It's working fine, but now I'm getting the current menu object. How can I get selected row data instead?

For example, I have right-clicked on "RE: New version of Telerik Trainer (1st one record)" and then click on reply to sender, so how can I get row object of current row.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the reference to the datarow by using the snippet below

```
function onSelect(e) {                           
    var lst =$("#listview-context-menu").getKendoListView();
    var row = lst.dataItem(e.target);
    console.log(row);
}
```

Please refer the [fiddle here](http://dojo.telerik.com/EMEZE) for a demo

Comment: If we have kendoDiagram instead of KendoListView. then can you please suggest me what would will be changes?